# How to get a list of Bitbucket repositories user permissions

Tags: repository, bitbucket, devops

I'm working to obtain a detailed list of the user permissions of Bitbucket repositories I have more than 100 repositories and also 80/90 users ...

I tried with API Rest of Bitbucket but I don't find it clear and concise at all ... I've used for example this query:

`http://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/workspaces/<workspace_id>/permissions/repositories?pagelen=100`

I have a list of the repositories but I need all users and be able to do it at once with all users with repositories permissions.

Any idea for how to do?